# How do I convert Java collections into Scala in Cassandra Datastax driver

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

The schema of my `Cassandra` table is

```
id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
description text,
messages list<text>,
image list<blob>,
primary text,
tags set<text>,
title text,
more text
```

I am able to retrieve a `ResultSet` from the table but I don't know how to map it into my model. The `Scala` `class` I want to model the row into is

```
case class Data (id: Option[UUID],
                              description: String,
                              messages: List[String],
                              image: Array[Byte], 
                              first: String,
                              tags: Set[String],
                              title: String,
                              more:String)
```

I know that the function `Row.getString("column name")` coverts `text` into `String` but I don't know what to do to convert the `list<text>`, `list<blob>` and `set<text>` into `scala classes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract set from resultSet and convert it to scala set, you can define a function as follows :-

```
 def convertToScalaSet(row: Row, columnName: String): Set[String] = 
  {

    val mayBeSet = Option(row.getSet(columnName, "String".getClass).toSet[String])

    mayBeSet match {
      case Some(set) if set.size > 0 => set
      case _ => Set[String]() //this case will cover both the possibilities of set being empty or none value
    }
  }
```

On Similar lines you can create a function that will convert to scala list

```
  def convertToScalaList(row: Row, columnName: String): List[String] = 
  {

    val mayBeList = Option(row.getList(columnName, "String".getClass).toList)

    mayBeList match {
      case Some(list) if list.size > 0 => list
      case _ => List[String]() //this case will cover both the possibilities of list being empty or none value
    }
  }
```

In your code then, you could call these methods as follows

```
  val row = resultSet.one()
  convertToScalaSet(row,"tags")
  convertToScalaList(row,"messages")
```

Comment: Thanks but `row.getList("messages","String".getClass).toList[String]` doesnt' compile. `toList` is undefined

Comment: `row.getList("messages","String".getClass).asScala.toList[String]` seem to work